# Why doesn't this button work correctly when the pointer is over the icon?

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

When the pointer is inside the icon's image area it doesn't work, and sends it to null. But if the pointer is next to the icon and inside the button it already works. Why?

The button is perfect, but when you click on the icon in the middle of the button it will submit like this:

[image: current output]

But it should appear like this:
[image: desired output]

```css
.searchButton2 {
    max-width: 130px;
    width: 50px;
    height: 45px;
    border: 3px solid red;
    background: #28b9ed;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 14px;
    margin-left: 45px;
    margin-top: 45px;
    outline: none;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css"> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<button type="submit" class="searchButton2" style="outline:none;" id="google-search" name="google-search"  data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Pesquisa Adprizes+" formaction="https://www.google.com/search?q=adprizes%2B+"><i class="fa fa-search fa-lg"></i></button>
```

```
<button type="submit" class="searchButton2" style="outline:none;" id="google-search" name="google-search"  data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Pesquisa Adprizes+" formaction="https://www.google.com/search?q=adprizes%2B+"><i class="fa fa-search fa-lg"></i></button>
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging using 'F12' and then going to console? Are there any messages shown there?

Comment: When doing F12 this appears: agency.min.js:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined
    at o (agency.min.js:1)
    at agency.min.js:1
    at agency.min.js:1

Comment: Did you not get a hint to that in your earlier, similar question?

Comment: I couldn't solve the problem and so I changed the system.

Answer (score 1):

For me it works when I add the 'form' tag. 
However, I do get cross-origin error, which is a whole different story. ( https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS/Errors )

```css
.searchButton2 {
    max-width: 130px;
    width: 50px;
    height: 45px;
    border: 3px solid red;
    background: #28b9ed;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 14px;
    margin-left: 45px;
    margin-top: 45px;
    outline: none;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css"> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<form>
<button type="submit" class="searchButton2" style="outline:none;" id="google-search" name="google-search"  data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Pesquisa Adprizes+" formaction="https://www.google.com/search?q=adprizes%2B+"><i class="fa fa-search fa-lg"></i></button>
</form>
```